# Streaming DRM protected video

Tags: video-streaming, video.js, drm, mpeg-dash

I am able to create segmented multi-drm protected videos following this link https://www.axinom.com/creating-multi-drm-protected-videos-with-free-tools/

the problem is that after creating encrypted segments and the playlist container **manifest.mpd** I tried to play using my dash-enabled videojs player. And the request responded `"DASH playlist request error at URL: http://192.168.0.106:3000/video/manifest.mpd"`.

After spending some time figuring out the problem I should respond those playlists as illustrated below
[image]

How can I do that? What is the process I should follow to stream those files as mentioned above?

Comment: Do you have a widevine server installed and configured?

Comment: @Kirubel this doesn't seem DRM related. That error seems to suggest a problem downloading the mpd. Are you using a browser based player? If so, did you set up CORS?

Comment: I'm using videojs for my player. I'm able to play any other mp4 videos from my server. But while streaming that mpd file it gives me Dash playlist request error. And I didn't setup CORS.